# Trouble targeting element

Tags: css

I am having trouble targeting an element in a nested `<ul>`.

In the following block, I am trying to target the `<a>` that comes after the parent `<li>`

```html
<ul class="wc-block-product-categories-list wc-block-product-categories-list--depth-0">
    <li class="wc-block-product-categories-list-item">
        <a style="" href="#"> <!-- Target this link -->
            <span class="wc-block-product-categories-list-item__name">text</span>
        </a>
        <ul class="wc-block-product-categories-list wc-block-product-categories-list--depth-1">
            <li class="wc-block-product-categories-list-item">
                <a style="" href="#">
                    <span class="wc-block-product-categories-list-item__name">text</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="wc-block-product-categories-list-item">
                <a style="" href="#">
                    <span class="wc-block-product-categories-list-item__name">text</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="wc-block-product-categories-list-item">
                <a style="" href="#">
                    <span class="wc-block-product-categories-list-item__name">text</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="wc-block-product-categories-list-item">
                <a style="" href="#">
                    <span class="wc-block-product-categories-list-item__name">text</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="wc-block-product-categories-list-item">
        <a style="" href="#"> <!-- Target this link -->
            <span class="wc-block-product-categories-list-item__name">text</span>
        </a>
        <ul class="wc-block-product-categories-list wc-block-product-categories-list--depth-1">
            <li class="wc-block-product-categories-list-item">
                <a style="" href="#">
                    <span class="wc-block-product-categories-list-item__name">text</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="wc-block-product-categories-list-item">
                <a style="" href="#">
                    <span class="wc-block-product-categories-list-item__name">text</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="wc-block-product-categories-list-item">
                <a style="" href="#">
                    <span class="wc-block-product-categories-list-item__name">text</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I've tried using child selectors (>), adjacent and general sibling selectors (~ and +), pseudo-classes (:first-child) but I can't reach that hyperlink.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `*--depth-0` parent class as reference:

```css
.wc-block-product-categories-list--depth-0 > li > a {

}
```

example:

```css
.wc-block-product-categories-list--depth-0 > li > a {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="wc-block-product-categories-list wc-block-product-categories-list--depth-0">
    <li class="wc-block-product-categories-list-item">
        <a style="" href="#"> <!-- Target this link -->
            <span class="wc-block-product-categories-list-item__name">text</span>
        </a>
        <ul class="wc-block-product-categories-list wc-block-product-categories-list--depth-1">
            <li class="wc-block-product-categories-list-item">
                <a style="" href="#">
                    <span class="wc-block-product-categories-list-item__name">text</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="wc-block-product-categories-list-item">
                <a style="" href="#">
                    <span class="wc-block-product-categories-list-item__name">text</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="wc-block-product-categories-list-item">
                <a style="" href="#">
                    <span class="wc-block-product-categories-list-item__name">text</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="wc-block-product-categories-list-item">
                <a style="" href="#">
                    <span class="wc-block-product-categories-list-item__name">text</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="wc-block-product-categories-list-item">
        <a style="" href="#"> <!-- Target this link -->
            <span class="wc-block-product-categories-list-item__name">text</span>
        </a>
        <ul class="wc-block-product-categories-list wc-block-product-categories-list--depth-1">
            <li class="wc-block-product-categories-list-item">
                <a style="" href="#">
                    <span class="wc-block-product-categories-list-item__name">text</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="wc-block-product-categories-list-item">
                <a style="" href="#">
                    <span class="wc-block-product-categories-list-item__name">text</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="wc-block-product-categories-list-item">
                <a style="" href="#">
                    <span class="wc-block-product-categories-list-item__name">text</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for ONLY the first child of the first li - then you  can use the li:first child to target that - if its just the first a of both the direct descendant li's - then remove the :first-child pseudo-selector.

Note the use of the classname of the UL - this allows the distinguishing of the first li since that class is unique.

```css
.wc-block-product-categories-list--depth-0 > li:first-child > a {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<ul class="wc-block-product-categories-list wc-block-product-categories-list--depth-0">
    <li class="wc-block-product-categories-list-item">
        <a style="" href="#"> <!-- Target this link -->
            <span class="wc-block-product-categories-list-item__name">text</span>
        </a>
        <ul class="wc-block-product-categories-list wc-block-product-categories-list--depth-1">
            <li class="wc-block-product-categories-list-item">
                <a style="" href="#">
                    <span class="wc-block-product-categories-list-item__name">text</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="wc-block-product-categories-list-item">
                <a style="" href="#">
                    <span class="wc-block-product-categories-list-item__name">text</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="wc-block-product-categories-list-item">
                <a style="" href="#">
                    <span class="wc-block-product-categories-list-item__name">text</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="wc-block-product-categories-list-item">
                <a style="" href="#">
                    <span class="wc-block-product-categories-list-item__name">text</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="wc-block-product-categories-list-item">
        <a style="" href="#"> <!-- Target this link -->
            <span class="wc-block-product-categories-list-item__name">text</span>
        </a>
        <ul class="wc-block-product-categories-list wc-block-product-categories-list--depth-1">
            <li class="wc-block-product-categories-list-item">
                <a style="" href="#">
                    <span class="wc-block-product-categories-list-item__name">text</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="wc-block-product-categories-list-item">
                <a style="" href="#">
                    <span class="wc-block-product-categories-list-item__name">text</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="wc-block-product-categories-list-item">
                <a style="" href="#">
                    <span class="wc-block-product-categories-list-item__name">text</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using a class name*, you can target the element if it's `not` a descendant of another li:

```css
:not(li) > ul > li > a {}
```

** just for fun and learning other cool ways to do the same thing...*

```css
:not(li) > ul > li > a {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="wc-block-product-categories-list wc-block-product-categories-list--depth-0">
    <li class="wc-block-product-categories-list-item">
        <a style="" href="#"> <!-- Target this link -->
            <span class="wc-block-product-categories-list-item__name">text</span>
        </a>
        <ul class="wc-block-product-categories-list wc-block-product-categories-list--depth-1">
            <li class="wc-block-product-categories-list-item">
                <a style="" href="#">
                    <span class="wc-block-product-categories-list-item__name">text</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="wc-block-product-categories-list-item">
                <a style="" href="#">
                    <span class="wc-block-product-categories-list-item__name">text</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="wc-block-product-categories-list-item">
                <a style="" href="#">
                    <span class="wc-block-product-categories-list-item__name">text</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="wc-block-product-categories-list-item">
                <a style="" href="#">
                    <span class="wc-block-product-categories-list-item__name">text</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="wc-block-product-categories-list-item">
        <a style="" href="#"> <!-- Target this link -->
            <span class="wc-block-product-categories-list-item__name">text</span>
        </a>
        <ul class="wc-block-product-categories-list wc-block-product-categories-list--depth-1">
            <li class="wc-block-product-categories-list-item">
                <a style="" href="#">
                    <span class="wc-block-product-categories-list-item__name">text</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="wc-block-product-categories-list-item">
                <a style="" href="#">
                    <span class="wc-block-product-categories-list-item__name">text</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="wc-block-product-categories-list-item">
                <a style="" href="#">
                    <span class="wc-block-product-categories-list-item__name">text</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```